# Consuming C# component from C++/CX and C#

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cx

I have created a simple control SimpleControl.xaml in C++/CX defined as:

```
<UserControl ..  > // Attributes omitted for reading simplicity
<Grid>

 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
 <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="PersonaPicture" ... />
    <Border x:Name="PhotoTextBackdrop" ... />
    <TextBlock x:Name="PersonaName" .../>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then this control is used in the following manner in a file “foo.xaml” that uses C++/CX as a code behind. SuperPanel inherits from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Panel and is defined in the TastyLib component (consumed by this C++/CX component). The 'fruity' namespace points to TastyLib. The TastyLib component is coded in C#:

```
</fruity:SuperPanel>
    <local:SimpleControl x:Name="gPerson1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="SaddleBrown" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <UserControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
</fruity:SuperPanel>
```

Setting a breakpoint and looking at the watch ,  I observed the following to be the children of the panel:

> child[0] was Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement, child[1] was
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle and child[2] was
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl

Now, in the watch I was expecting the first child to be a SimpleControl, but instead it is a UIElement, which is surprising to me. Where did that come from? Why is it showing an ancestor of SimpleControl as child[0] while it can still recognize a UserControl as child[2] ?

I recreated another SimpleControl in a C# component that uses TastyLib (So this SimpleControl was also written in C# and did not use C++/CX), and put that control within another SuperPanel, exactly like the first case (but all in C# this time). On setting the same breakpoint and viewing in the watch window I saw child[0] to be what I was expecting -  a SimpleControl. In this case:

> child[0] was FooProject.SimpleControl, child[1] was Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle and child[2] was Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl

What could be the root cause of this dichotomy? Shouldn’t a control written in C++/CX behave the exact way as a control written in C# (when consuming the same component written in C#) ? I’m guessing that it’s something to do with component interoperability.  Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds more like you are confused about the difference between the logical and the visual object tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the research I've done, the issue is that a winRT boundary is crossed in the case of the control written in C++/CX so when the CLR asks for the type, the object returns back Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement from its GetRuntimeClassName implementation (why?).

In case of control developed using C#, no winRT boundry is crossed and a .NET object is speaking to another .NET object and hence the type is known.